# How to add javascript widgets in BIRT reports

Tags: javascript, eclipse, report, birt

I am trying to extend BIRT for include a Report Item that is based on a javascript widget. I am not able to figure out how to include the js files used by a widget in the reportitemPresentation. I went through the 'RotatedText' example and tried to override the onRowSets method:

```
public Object onRowSets( IRowSet[] rowSets ) throws BirtException
{
StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
Str.append("<script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>">);

.....//added code to initialize the widget.

return str.toString();
```

This added the script in the body of HTML but did not execute. Please ignore the syntax errors as the script tag was correctly added in the HTML.

In addition, I also want to add the code to initialize the widget:

```
$("#jqxbutton").jqxButton({ width: '150', height: '25'});
```

How do I do the following:

1. Include the js files of a widget in the html head tag.
2. How to include the code to initialize the widget and set some properties for the widget. For eg. How can I add the code for

   $(document).ready(){  // initialize the widget, add some properties};

What classes do I have to extend, which method to override? Any examples would be helpful. What is the right way to include the widget?

Comment: You said "This added the script in the body of HTML but did not execute.". I don't see anything to execute here (I mean: no statements), only script includes. Besides, the RotatedText item is an item like the builtin items, e.g. it includes logic to draw itself (the drawing code is called from BIRT). This is something different than your Javascript widget, which generates Javasript to to be executed by the browser (not called from BIRT).

Comment: @hvb, The code to initialize was also added in the string append but did not execute. I am more interested in knowing if this is the right way to include js files in BIRT. It adds the script tag in the body of the html and not the head. I added the scripts later in the Head section of the RunFragement.jsp and it worked but this according to me is not the right way to dynamically add js scripts.

Comment: It is important to know the difference between client-side JS and JS used inside BIRT reports. What you are trying to do looks like client-side JS. I can't help you, because I never generate HTML with BIRT (only PDF, XLSX, DOC) and thus I don't use client-side JS. I only use JS script files for sharing BIRT report logic.